# Flash Light and other buttons not visible in ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner

Tags: xamarin, zxing

I am using below code to scan bar codes. I have set the cancel and flash buttons texts but its not visible on the UI. Its working fine in iOS but not in Android.
See below code

```
    public async Task StartScan()
    {
        var scanPage = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
        this.cancelTimer = new CancellationTokenSource();
        scanPage.AutoFocus();
        scanPage.TopText = "Place the barcode between the red line";
        scanPage.CameraUnsupportedMessage = "Camera doesnt supports AUTOFOCUS.";
        scanPage.BottomText = "If it doesnt autofocus, touch the screen to autofocus";
        scanPage.CancelButtonText = "<< Back";
        scanPage.FlashButtonText = "Turn Flash";
        scanPage.UseCustomOverlay = false;

        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3, 0), () =>
        {
            scanPage.AutoFocus();
            //  scanPage.BottomText = "focusing";
            return true;
        });
        ZXing.Result result = null;
        CancellationTokenSource cts = this.cancelTimer;
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 2, 0);
        Device.StartTimer(ts, () =>
        {
            if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (result == null)
            {
                scanPage.AutoFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        result = await scanPage.Scan(new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
        {
            TryHarder = false,
            AutoRotate = false,
            UseNativeScanning = true,
            PossibleFormats = GetAvailableFormats(),
        });
        if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result.Text))
        {
            await Stop();                
            await ProcessResult(result.Text);
        }
        await Stop();
    }
```

So from the above code, Bottom and Top texts are appearing but not the buttons for which code is like below.
 scanPage.CancelButtonText = "<< Back";
 scanPage.FlashButtonText = "Turn Flash";

Can anyone help me to get this?